# Can I make the complete backend of my app in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, flutter, backend

I am currently working to make a dynamic studying app in which contents get updated daily. Can I use firebase as my server and use node js to communicate between the app and the backend. I am using flutter to create my app.

Comment: nodejs is not a bad idea. php does sound good too

Comment: I want the app to be dynamic and and update contents like questions, daily facts etc. Can I do this all with nodejs only or I will need any other programming language too. Please reply. I would be very grateful to you if you could eexplain it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can write a node.js backend service to achieve this.  Take a look of various web, and REST framework available for javascript and you can use those to help speed up the development of your node.js backend.  A popular choice for this is Express, https://expressjs.com/.

Once you build your backend, your frontend (sometime refer to as client app) can be anything from mobile app like your in this case using flutter to desktop app, web app, other services etc... can consume contents that your backend provides.

Comment: I can't explain how much satisfied I am feeling after reading your answer. Thanks a lot